# C-state in VM: needed or no?

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu

Would it cause any difference if the cstate is enabled or not on a VM?

```
cat /sys/module/*_idle/parameters/max_cstate
```

So not on the hypervisor, rather on a VM.

Any virtualization, question in general regarding the VM guests c-state setting.

Or the c-state state on the VM doesn't affects anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not generally but EC2 will pass it along if you are the only client on the CPU;

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/processor_state_control.html

> The following instance types provide the ability for an operating system to control processor C-states and P-states:...

Comment: wow, thanks :O I went through the DOC, but didn't found where it says that it will pass the setting to the hypervisor, when it is the only one using the CPU? Can you pls point that part out? Or it is in another DOC? Many thanks!